# Soritng Ascending and descending order after clicking on table header?

Tags: sorting, selenium

I am using Selenium *WebDriver* with *Java*.
I have a table where I have to click on header of each column and want to validate whether sorting functionality is working correctly or not. I need to check for both `Asc` and `Desc` order.

So I have to take the count of the table first and the get the header text so that I click on each *col 1-1* and then need to validate the sorting.

How can achieve my expected result. Below is the HTML source code:

```
 <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvClinicalTrait" style="border-color:appworkspace;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr class="gridTitleBar">
            <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvClinicalTrait','Sort$TraitDate')">Date Collected</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvClinicalTrait','Sort$TraitDesc')">Clinical Trait Data</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvClinicalTrait','Sort$TraitSourceDesc')">Source</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvClinicalTrait','Sort$TraitValue')">Value</a></th>
        </tr><tr class="gridBody" align="left">
            <td>11/6/2008</td><td style="width:200px;">A1C</td><td style="width:200px;">d</td><td>6.00</td>
        </tr><tr class="gridBody" align="left">
            <td>9/17/2008</td><td style="width:200px;">BP</td><td style="width:200px;">e)</td><td>104/54</td>
        </tr><tr class="gridBody" align="left">
            <td>7/12/2008</td><td style="width:200px;">BP</td><td style="width:200px;">g</td><td>124/56</td>
        </tr><tr class="gridBody" align="left">
            <td>6/21/2008</td><td style="width:200px;">BP</td><td style="width:200px;">t</td><td>110/72</td>
        </tr><tr class="gridBody" align="left">
            <td>6/14/2008</td><td style="width:200px;">BP</td><td style="width:200px;">n</td><td>120/70</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No..  I don't  know how can i do? And i am new to selenium as well....

Answer (score -1):

> How can achieve my expected result. Below is the HTML source code:

1. you need to have list or array with expected result.
2. You need to create loop like this for every test:

   ```
   List<string> expectedValues = new List<string>("12","13","14");

   int expectedNumber = expectedValues.Count;

   int tdNumber = 2;

   for (int i=1; i< expectedNumber; i++)
   ```

   {
           string result = driver.Find(by.xpath("//div[@id ='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvClinicalTrait']/tr["+ i +"]/td["+tdNumber+"]")).Text;

   ```
       if (result != expectedValues[i])

           Assert.Fail("Wrong value!")
   ```

   }

I didnt try this code, but even if its wrong it's will be pretty close to code that you need.